# How to copy/paste properly in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

For some reason when I copy a file from one folder and paste to a target folder (highlighted) it pastes the file several levels up, instead of in the target folder. I then have search up or down for the file and drag it.

How can I copy (Command-C), highlight a target folder, then paste (Command-V)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Finder pastes into the folder you're currently in, which you can identify via the window title bar.

It does *not* paste into the selected folder when in list view (`Cmd-2`). It only does this in column view (`Cmd-3`), and that view also changes the current folder when changing the selection.

---

You can create a Service using Automator that executes `ditto` or `cp` based on the previously copied file(s) and the current selection. Setting it to `Cmd-V` might have unexpected side effects, since this shortcut wouldn't be context-aware: pasting when editing file names wouldn't work anymore

Comment: The same behavior applies for at least *View ▸ as ␣*, *New Folder* and *Show View Options* — you'd have to make a lot of services to have it changed consistently.

Answer (score 6):

As a long-time Mac user, I've never EVER used copy/paste for filesystem management. It's always struck me as an odd windows thing.

The "proper Mac way" as I know it is to use a drag with modifier keys. Holding down option while dragging will make a copy, holding down command will force a move if you're dragging to another volume, and holding down command and option will create an alias.

Copy/paste does work, but the paste location will be whatever folder is open, not whichever folder is selected. So, copying the selected file, double-clicking the destination folder, and then pasting will work the way you want it to.

IMO, option-dragging is faster.

Comment: Thanks for this! Finally I know how to copy properly in the Finder! My copies always went into the wrong folder...

Comment: I consider Apple's finder a completely braindamaged product, and I consider the pasting into the top-directory a serious bug that plagues me for years now. But you pointed me to a nice workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Option dragging is good, but it requires you to remember the correct modifier keys. And the whole point of a WYSIWYG WIMPy GUI interface is to make things evident and discoverable - to NOT require reading the manuals (or stackoverflow) to discover how to do something.  I.e. in many ways providing ONLY option dragging is a throwback to the early days, before people figured out how GUIs should work.

Comment: It's a little bit less heinous when you consider that option as a copy modifier was widely used across lots of Mac apps at the time — it may have even been in their developer UI guidelines. So you only had to learn this once, and it worked the same in the Finder, Photoshop, Excel, Word, ClarisWorks, etc. In many cases it still does!

Comment: Dragging is not really a viable option when you have thousands of elements in the tree view.  That's quite a journey and you may never make it before running out of trackpad or jiggle motion along the table header.  Two windows side-by-side would fix that, but that's kind of annoying too.